# Error in extracting Raster Values Greater than 0.5 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator, gdal-translate

I want to extract raster values which is greater than 0.5 .I Used Raster Calculator to create a new raster which have values greater than 0.5 .

Formula for Raster Calculator:

`("raster" > 0.5) * "raster"`

but it create a tiff having values from 0 .
Now I want to change 0 to No Data

For this i tried Raster--> Conversion --> Translate(Convert Format)

`gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 -of GTiff input.tif output.tif`

But output does'nt have correct values.

Is there any other way to do this by Python Console or by GDAL .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following in the **Raster Calculator** to get all values greater than 0.5 and anything else be shown as `nodata`:

```
"raster" / ("raster" > 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanx @Joseph it works :)

Comment: @User18 - Most welcome, glad it worked ;)

Comment: @User18 - The `nodata` cells still count as cells, they haven't been removed. So the count number should be the same. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: It is resolved now.. actually i selected wrong input . hope u dont mind :)

Comment: @User18 - No problem at all, glad you got it resolved :)